# The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly. #15495

Tags: .net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019, .net-5

I have built a web project in VS 2019, worked a lot witout problems on that (Asp.Net Core 5.0) Web App and suddenly it started to appear an error on that Web Project:

Error MSB4018

> The "CreateAppHost" task failed unexpectedly.
> Microsoft.NET.HostModel.HResultException: 800703EE at
> Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.<>c__DisplayClass2_0.g__UpdateResources|1()
> at Microsoft.NET.HostModel.RetryUtil.RetryOnWin32Error(Action func) at
> Microsoft.NET.HostModel.AppHost.HostWriter.CreateAppHost(String
> appHostSourceFilePath, String appHostDestinationFilePath, String
> appBinaryFilePath, Boolean windowsGraphicalUserInterface, String
> assemblyToCopyResorcesFrom) at
> Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.CreateAppHost.ExecuteCore() at
> Microsoft.NET.Build.Tasks.TaskBase.Execute() at
> Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
> at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.d__26.MoveNext() MyApp.Web
> C:\Program
> Files\dotnet\sdk\5.0.102\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets
> 460

[image]

Config details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/15495).

I restarted the computer, I run VS in admin mode, nothing helps to get rid of this error.

Comment: You can refer to the [link](https://github.com/dotnet/sdk/issues/10708).You can try to clean and rebuild.`avifatal `said it will be helpful sometimes but its very very long.

Comment: the issue disappeared as it appeared, unexpectedly, but after few hours, rebuilds, computer restarts, ".vs" folder removal, even Visual Studio repairing and reinstalling.

Answer (score 4):

I hit the exact same thing today.  Having our sysadmin put in an exception for it.  Grr Antivirus!

Adding a picture here for clarity for future folks.

[image]

Comment: Confirmed adding the exception to our AV rules did it.  Compiling works again.

Answer (score 2):

The Eset antivirus detected in the

```
myapp\obj\debug\.net5.0\apphost.exe
```

a "danger" and blocked it for an unknown reason. The compilation was impossible.

Answer (score 1):

For me, it wasn't antivirus or permissions required. I had my project in a Google Drive folder and it worked well until I installed some updates and the "CreateAppHost" error appeared.

Taking the project folder outside Google Drive fixed it for me.