# How do I stop the CreateAppHost task from failing in VS2022 (C# forms)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022

When I go to run my project it says there are build errors, when I look it tells me that CreateAppHost is failing unexpectedly. It has been doing this for a while now, and I have been using it on visual studios 2022 edition. Here is some images:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxrAY.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNdbh.png)

I've tried deleting the whole createapphost section of the code, but that didn't work and I'm unsure what to try next as this is my first time using c# forms.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65903138/the-createapphost-task-failed-unexpectedly-15495

Comment: Also check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61067765/the-createapphost-task-failed-unexpectedly-msb4018